# Action Mailer: Send shopping cart view to email at checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would like for an email of my shopping cart view with all of the orders to be sent to the store owner when the customer clicks on a continue check out button.

I already have a contact form working so I have the admin gmail setting set up in the configuration/stpm_settings.

I am not sure if I am even on the right track but this is what I have so far:
I created a route:

```
get :send_order_mail, to: 'orders#send_order_mail', as: :send_order_mail
```

I created a mailer

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default :from => "admins@gmail.com"

  def order_send(order, client)
    @order = order
    @client = client
    mail(to: "admins@gmail.com", subject: "New Order")
  end
end
```

A submit button on the bottom of my cart/show.html.erb

```
<div class="shopping-cart">

  <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
 <h4 class="text-right">Subtotal: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.subtotal %></span></h4>
 <h4 class="text-right">Shipping: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.shipping %></span></h4>
  <h4 class="text-right">Order Total: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.total %></span></h4>

<%= link_to "Send Order by email", :controller => "orders", :action => "send_order_mail" %>
</div>
```

this is my carts controller

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
    @shipping = params[:shipping]

    OrderMailer.order_send(@order, @client).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Order has been sent."
    redirect_to carge_path(@order.id)
  end

  def order_subtotal
   @order_items.sum(:total_price)
  end
```

Comment: You've described your setup, but you don't seem to be posing a question here. Instead, let me ask one: does it work when you try it? If not, what problems are you having? Are there error messages? A console log?

Comment: You also don't need a route for your mailer.  Instead you simple call the mailer method in the controller handling the 'continue to checkout' action.

Comment: Currently nothing happens. I guess my question is how do you you tell the mailer to send the code that is in the cart view. From what I have read on mailers you create a mailer view. Would I still need to do this and some how render the code from the cart view?